# what is standard restrictions for facebook comment box

Tags: facebook

i use facebook comment box moderation tool. Under the Settings menu, there is an option :

Black Listed Words ->Standard Facebook Restrictions

where can i find the all list to check some words?

thaks.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t know if there is a publicly available list.

If there was, I could easily look up which words are on it and chose others to insult you while posting … which would be defeating the use of such a filter a bit. (But the effectiveness of such filters is questionable anyways. If you block *badword*, a “creative” user will most likely try other forms of spelling it, *b*a*d*w*o*r*d* or using *1337 5P34K* or something like that.)

When activating the Profanity Block List for a Facebook page, the only explanation they offer is,

> Profanity Blocklist
>
> Facebook will block the most commonly reported words and phrases marked as offensive by the broader community.